# ¿Como predefinir columnas en un DataGrid llenado con los datos de una base de datos?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Quiero darle un estilo ya definido de columnas con su titulo y todo  a un DataGrid, presento los registros de una tabla llamada usuarios donde utilizo el sieguiente codigo hecho desde C# con Visual Studio 2017

```
public void mostrarTabla()
    {
        String consulta = "select Nombre,ApellidoP,ApellidoM,Sexo,Telefono,Edad,Puesto from usuarios;";
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(consulta,new BaseDeDatos().obtenerConexion());
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        dataGridUsuarios.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }
```

Me muestra bien los datos con el nombre de las columnas correctas pero se ve todo muy junto y esteticamente mal.. y no encuentro en la configuracion que facilita Visual Studio para el codigo nada de como mejorarlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te lo explicare por la forma de interface.

Primero creamos el `DataGrid`, posterior a el se tiene un boton en la parte superior derecho(tipo flecha), al hacerle click se desplega un menu donde se tiene la opcion de **edit column**(editar columna):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al hacer click e aparecera una nueva ventana donde podras crear tus columnas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agregas tantas columnas necesites, una vez creadas seleccionas una a una para darles un tamaño definido con la propiedad width.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo yo le di 120 para nombre y apellido, 80 para sexo y 70 para edad.

Comment: Muchas gracias aun que en mi caso como lo realizo con interfaz wpf(no se si tenga que ver) no me aparece la flecha pero me dio la idea para buscarlo en propiedades y ahi encontre algo similar ya solo segui con hacer lo de dataGridTexColumn y darle tamaño..
Solo hay algo que no puedo hacer es asociar los registros de la base de datos con cada columna.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer con la propiedad Columns de esta manera:

```
dataGridUsuarios.Columns(0).Width = 100;
dataGridUsuarios.Columns(1).Width = 150;
```

Y asi con el resto de columnas, la  coleccion de columnas siempre empieza en cero para el primer `item`

saludos

Comment: Lo intente como esta y me marca error al utilizar dataGridUsuarios.Columns(0);
incluso si tuilizo
dataGridUsuarios.Columns(0).Width = 100;

Comment: Cual es el error que te esta dando?

Answer (score 1):

creo que lo que necesitas es configurar la tabla para que se rellene o se ajuste automaticamente al titulo o contenido de las columnas.
en ese orden de ideas quizas te sirva esta configuracion.

[image: esta es la configuracion que rellena las columanas dependiendo de su contenido]

[image: anexo imagen]